# Why do capacitors behave like this in Circuit Wizard? How is it in real life?

Tags: capacitor, simulation

I recorded [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vgmpt46diMc) to show a situation in Circuit Wizard software.  I am not sure what the right answer is.

Can anybody explain is it exactly happening like this in real life , or just because it is a 'simulator' it creates some weird results regarding the behaviors of capacitors?

For example,

1. How can a capacitor in an open circuit still be charged with only one pole contact of the battery?
2. Why does contact from positive or negative pole of the battery create a completely different response?
3. Why do 'no wire' and 'wire but switch off' circuits give different results?

[image: Circuit Wizard]

Comment: Supposedly there is a manual somewhere that would describe what kind of models there are for components and how they are simulated. If there isn't, how could anyone simulate anything with a simulator that has unknown component models and simulation behaviour? Weird things also happen in real life, but there is usually a known explanation for them. Try asking people who sell the product how their product ends up behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: *Why can a capacitor in an open still be charged with only one pole contact of the battery?* - if you fill a bucket full of water and then climb the steps to the top of your house, how much water is in the bucket?

Comment: The bucket should have equal amount of water. Unless it rains. Or the bucket leaks. Or water evaporates under sunshine. Or if temperatue changes and it boils or freezes. Which brings us back to the question how the Bucket Simulator Wizard which costs money and has no documentation how it models the bucket or the environmet it is in.

Comment: Note that some types of capacitor have a "memory" effect and are therefore "charged" when measuring their "residual voltage" which can also change depending on the grip effect, by the difference in body temperature.

Comment: Some conversation is going on here but I think on some other side subjects. But my questions were very simple. For example if we touch only one leg of the capacitor to the positive pole of the battery, will there be any charging, or not.. in real life? (because simulation shows that there will be)